# ng-animate using javascript with angular version 1.2.0

Tags: angularjs

I have this HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"  class="fade">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

and JS:

```
app.animation('fade', function() {
    return {
        setup : function(element) {
            alert("abc");
            element.css({'opacity': 0}); 
        },
        enter : function(element, done, memo) {
            alert("def");
            element.animate({'opacity': 1}, function() {
                done(); 
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Throws error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module HR due to: 
[$animate:notcsel] Expecting class selector starting with '.' got 'fade'.
```

I can get rid of the error by doing `app.animation('.fade', function() {` but then the alerts dont fire.

Anyone knows what is happening? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: ".fade" is required by animation function check @ http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$animate:notcsel

Comment: Thanks. But why dont the alerts work?

Comment: Check the updated answer with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup is not support in animation function in angular version 1.2.0

Try with below code:

```
  app.animation('fade', function() {
        return {

            enter : function(element, done, memo) {
                alert("def");
                element.animate({'opacity': 1}, function() {
                    done(); 
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Below is the working example:

<kbd>[Working Example of Javascript Animation in Angular js 1.2.0](http://plnkr.co/edit/CEFc6FbXtPdnwi1W7FXr?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if I'm a little late, but I think i found the solution.

The name needs to be .fade as the error states, like this:

```
app.animation('.fade', function() {
    return {
        setup : function(element) {
            alert("abc");
            element.css({'opacity': 0}); 
        },
        enter : function(element, done, memo) {
            alert("def");
            element.animate({'opacity': 1}, function() {
                done(); 
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See more [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/day/11) under javascript animations